# Runtime of a Java Desktop program is unstable

Tags: java, performance, runtime

When we run same code with same inputs, we expect to give outputs within same time. But my Java desktop application generates outputs with a little change, such as 51, 49, 48, 50, 47 seconds. Also, the runtime change is not only descending. The example above is a real results I took from 5 different runs. I couldn't find any rational reasons for this change.

Is there anybody who can explain me why every runtime takes different durations?

Comment: Are you using threads? Without to see the code it's difficult to answer.

Comment: Hard to help without any code snippet and any idea of what your app does

Comment: I'm not using threads but I'm using ArrayLists intensely. But that shouldn't change the runtime, am I wrong?

Comment: The time the GC takes can change the result quite a bit. I would try to avoid creating objects by doing a memory profile and reduce your largest garbage producers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM, which is what allows java programs to be run, needs to get the computer ready to run the program. 
The time needed to preform this is different each time due to a few reasons, such as the load on the computer at that moment.

The differences occur because each time, the JVM takes longer to preform said task. Each time the reasons are slightly different and so each time the duration would be slightly different.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Does this mean that to get same runtime results for a Java program is practically impossible? Because, even I close every user programs and services, the runtime varies.

Comment: It does.
You can't close all programs and processes and those you can't close typically take up the most time.

Comment: Is there any way to stabilize Java like MATLAB? Because MATLAB uses resources in greedy way and runtime doesn't change.